# Send data from one class to another

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, service

I have foreground service and need to do work on it. I get data from multiple sensors and I am currently sending them by constructor:

```
 new MainMeranie(latitude, longitude, altitude, pressureAccuracy, GPSaltitude).start(); //first class needs to send data approximately every second
```

I know that its wrong because then previous variable data in the second class gets deleted (nulled)

```
public class MainMeranie extends Thread { //this is second class
    static Double[] latitude = new Double[MAX_VALUE];
    static Double[] longitude = new Double[MAX_VALUE];
    static Doubl...//because it is executed by constructor all of variables needs to be static and I think this is not efficient way to do this.. or?
    public MainMeranie(Double latitude, Double longitude, Double altitude, int pressureAccuracy, Double GPSaltitude) { 
        MainMeranie.latitude[i] = latitude*111139;
        MainMeranie.longitude[i] = longitude*111139;
        MainMe....
}
public void run() {...} //all work done here after constructor sets data
```

This needs to run on the foreground (it already is). I need second class to remember that data so it cant be activity or?? activity gets deleted when i kill app. I am starting a new thread every time because there is a lot of conditions and cycles..

What is the best, efficient way to do this?

Comment: If you want to remember the data and later use in activity/fragment to show or work on it why don't you use preferences, if data is small or even use database if there are multiple entries.

Comment: Hmm so let everything be like it is and all data of static variables save to sql database. Thats interesting idea